# Bootstrap form fields as buttons

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use multiple buttons in my bootstrap form as an alternate to a dropdown menu.I know I can have multiple submit buttons and then check in Flask, which one was clicked, but I'm trying to aim for a user to be able to select multiple buttons for a field without submitting the form, and then have a final unrelated submit button for the entire form.

I'm not sure if this is even a possibility within Bootstrap because this doesn't seem to be a normal HTML form field. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not just use checkboxes styled to look like buttons?

Comment: Completely forgot about that option. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this?

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="inputbtn1">
<input type="text" id="inputbtn2">
<input type="text" id="inputbtn3">
</form>

<button onclick="$('#inputbtn1').val( 'Whatever value you want here' )">Option 1</button>
<button onclick="$('#inputbtn2').val( 'Whatever value you want here' )">Option 2</button>
<button onclick="$('#inputbtn3').val( 'Whatever value you want here' )">Option 3</button>
```

[JsFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/24465/)

When the user clicks on the button, a value is set to the input. You can have this input field hidden if you want by changing it to `<input type="hidden" id="inputbtn1">`.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not familiar with Flask, but am quite so with Bootstrap. Why not try out [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic)? I'd highly recommend checking out both parts of a tutorial series on it by [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/184-formtastic-part-1) to learn it. They provide a lot of source code. Being a user of Formtastic for a while, it's quite a handy tool.